# Mocking an autowired field using mockito gives null response in rest call

Tags: rest, junit, mockito

I am using spring boot and mockito. I have autowired one class i.e, BDSRequest and in Junit Test class, i have used @Spy and @InjectMocks annotations. but while calling rest services in Junits, i am getting response (bdsCustomerHoldings) as null and assertion is failing. How to test this rest call with out mocking rest template like mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Constants.BDS_REST_URL, bdsRequest,
                    BDSCustomerHoldings.class) ?

```
class BDSRestCall
{

    @Autowired
    BDSRequest bdsRequest;

    public BDSCustomerHoldings getBDSCustomerInfo(String channelId, String customerId, String cinSuffix,
            String countryCode) {

        logger.info("prepareRequestForBDS");
        Header header = new Header();
        header.setMsgId(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20));
        header.setChannelId(channelId);
        header.setCountryCode(countryCode);
        header.setRecordTimeStamp(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_FORMATTER).format(LocalDateTime.now()));

        TxnRequest txnRequest = new TxnRequest();
        txnRequest.setIdDoc(customerId);
        txnRequest.setIdDocSuffix(cinSuffix);
        txnRequest.setIdDoctype("");
        txnRequest.setInsurerCode("");

        bdsRequest.setHeader(header);
        bdsRequest.setTxnRequest(txnRequest);

        logger.info("BDS request " + bdsRequest);

        BDSCustomerHoldings bdsResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(Constants.BDS_REST_URL, bdsRequest,
                BDSCustomerHoldings.class);
        logger.info("BDS Response : " + bdsResponse);

        return bdsResponse;
    }
}
```

**Junit:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class BDSRestCallTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private BDSRestCall bdsRestCall;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Spy
    private BDSRequest bdsRequest;



    @Test
        public void getBDSCustomerInfoExceptionTest() {
            BDSCustomerHoldings bdsCustomerHoldings = bdsRestCall.getBDSCustomerInfo("SG", "S9718016D",
                    "00", "SG");
            System.out.println("response is " + bdsCustomerHoldings);
            assertNotNull("response is not null", bdsCustomerHoldings);
        }

}
```

Comment: You need to mock the restTemplate.postForObject() call

Comment: i would like to test without mocking restTemplate.postForObject()

Comment: Then inject a real RestTemplate instead of injecting a mock one. A mock doesn't do anything other than what you tell it to do.

Comment: I would suggest you mock the restTemplate call because an actual API call may result in different responses in different conditions.For example if the service you are calling is down will result in status 500 even though your test case is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we are using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), then we should use mocking the response of restTemplate like below

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(), bdsRequest, BDSCustomerInsuranceHoldings.class)).thenReturn(sampleBDSCustomerInsuranceHoldings());
```

Then it will give mock response.